# Get value in Array [Symfony2 - Payum]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, paypal, payum

When the user add some products in the cart, the products are save in the entity commande that will contain the price, quantity , description etc...

```
s:10:"complement";s:9:"test test";}s:7:"priceHT";d:520;s:8:"priceTTC";d:624.25;s:5:"token";s:40:"50908802a1c1f0daf19e60277e336d6ab49142de";}
```

I want to get PriceHT in the entity commande so i can send it to paypal.

I'm using Payum (1.0.0).

I have this error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getPriceTTC" of class
>   "FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes".

This is the result of dump($commande);

```
Commandes {#1175 ▼
  -id: 87
  -user: User {#922 ▶}
  -confirm: false
  -date: DateTime {#1173 ▶}
  -reference: 0
  -commande: array:6 [▼
    "tva" => array:1 [▶]
    "entity" => array:1 [▶]
    "address" => array:8 [▶]
    "priceHT" => 47.0
    "priceTTC" => 56.42
    "token" => "0a044567dfe10f5594e8a5f1a9a632a66fd30b01"
  ]
  #number: null
  #description: null
  #clientEmail: null
  #clientId: null
  #totalAmount: null
  #currencyCode: null
  #details: []
  #creditCard: null
}
```

This is what i have done so far:

```
 public function validationCommandeAction($id)
    {
        $gatewayName = 'express_euro';
        $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $commande = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Commandes')->find($id);
        if (!$commande || $commande->getConfirm() == 1)
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Your order doesn t exist');
        $commande = $storage->create();
        $commande->setUser($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
        $commande->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $commande->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
        $commande->setClientId($this->getUser()->getId());
        $commande->setClientEmail($this->getUser()->getEmail());

        $commande->setTotalAmount($commande->getPriceTTC());

        $commande->setConfirm(1);
        $commande->setReference($this->container->get('setNewReference')->reference()); //Service
        $storage->update($commande);
        $em->flush();

        $captureToken = $this->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
            $gatewayName,
            $commande,
            'complete' // the route to redirect after capture;
        );
        return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }
```

**ADD:**

```
public function bill()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $generator = $this->container->get('security.secure_random');
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $address = $session->get('address');
        $cart = $session->get('cart');
        $commande = array();
        $totalHT = 0;
        $totalTVA = 0;

        $address = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Address')->find($address['address']);
        $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('cart')));

        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $priceHT = ($entity->getPrice() * $cart[$entity->getId()]);
            $priceTTC = ($entity->getPrice() * $cart[$entity->getId()] / $entity->getTva()->getMultiplicate());
            $totalHT += $priceHT;

            if (!isset($commande['tva']['%' . $entity->getTva()->getValue()]))
                $commande['tva']['%' . $entity->getTva()->getValue()] = round($priceTTC - $priceHT, 2);


            else
                $commande['tva']['%' . $entity->getTva()->getValue()] += round($priceTTC - $priceHT, 2);

            $totalTVA += round($priceTTC - $priceHT, 2);
            $commande['entity'][$entity->getId()] = array(
                'from' => $entity->getAirport(),
                'to' => $entity->getAirport1(),
                'quantity' => $cart[$entity->getId()],
                'priceHT' => round($entity->getPrice(), 2),
                'priceTTC' => round($entity->getPrice() / $entity->getTva()->getMultiplicate(), 2));
        }

        $commande['address'] = array('surname' => $address->getSurname(),
            'name' => $address->getName(),
            'phone' => $address->getPhone(),
            'address' => $address->getAddress(),
            'zipcode' => $address->getZipcode(),
            'city' => $address->getCity(),
            'country' => $address->getCountry(),
            'complement' => $address->getComplement());

        $commande['priceHT'] = round($totalHT, 2);
        $commande['priceTTC'] = round($totalHT + $totalTVA, 2);
        $commande['token'] = bin2hex($generator->nextBytes(20));

        return $commande;

    }
```

Comment: show where your method getPriceTTC

Comment: The method getPriceTTC is in the public function bill(). check my post on top.

Comment: @LBA I tried to do that `$entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('cart')));
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $commande->setTotalAmount($priceTTC = ($entity->getPrice() * $cart[$entity->getId()] / $entity->getTva()->getMultiplicate()));

        }`   it seem working but on paypal is showing 0,56E , but the amount should be 56E. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done to get The totalAmount and description.

```
public function validationCommandeAction($id)
        {   $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
            $gatewayName = 'express_euro';
            $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes');
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $commande = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Commandes')->find($id);
            dump($commande);

            if (!$commande || $commande->getConfirm() == 1)
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Your order doesn t exist');
            $commande = $storage->create();
            $commande->setUser($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
            $commande->setDate(new \DateTime());
            $commande->setCurrencyCode('EUR');
            $commande->setClientId($this->getUser()->getId());
            $commande->setClientEmail($this->getUser()->getEmail());
            $commande->setNumber(uniqid());
            $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('cart')));
            foreach ($entities as $entity) {
                $commande->setTotalAmount($priceTTC = round($entity->getPrice() / $entity->getTva()->getMultiplicate()*100, 2));
                $commande->setDescription($entity->getAirport());
            }
            $commande->setConfirm(1);
            $commande->setReference($this->container->get('setNewReference')->reference()); //Service
            $storage->update($commande);

            $em->flush();

            $captureToken = $this->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
                $gatewayName,
                $commande,
                'complete' // the route to redirect after capture;
            );
            return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
        }
```